# Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, contract

Getting this error! creation of local errored:**strong text**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.5;
contract local{

   uint256 count;
   function getter() public view returns(uint256) {
       return count ;
   }

   constructor (uint256 change){
       count  = change;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a non-empty unsigned integer value to the constructor since you have declared a variable of this type in the constructor.

In Remix IDE, you can do that under the `Deploy & run transactions` tab, next to the orange `Deploy` button. In my example, I passed the value `123`.

[image: screenshot]